# Monotonic functions that converges to 0 when $x \rightarrow +\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $g(x)$ monotonically tends to $0$ as $x \rightarrow +\infty$, does there exist an $\alpha \gt 0$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}x^\alpha g(x)=0$?

Comment: Consider $g(x)=1/ln(2+|x|)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in the general case.

Counter-example :

For $x>e^1$, consider :
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$$

No $\alpha$ can work.